Show that a specific piecewise sequence is monotonic.
I want to prove that the sequence $(x_n)_{n \ \in \ \mathbb{N}}$ defined below
$$\begin{cases}  
x_1 > 2 \\
x_{n+1}= \frac{1}{2}(x_n+\frac{2}{x_n}),\ n \in \ \mathbb{N}. 
\end{cases}$$
is monotonic.
I think the sequence is monotonically decreasing, however, I don't know how to prove it. I showed that $(x_n)_{n \ \in \ \mathbb{N}}$ is strictly positive in an attempt to show that
$$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<1, \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N},$$
and conclude that the sequence is monotonically decreasing.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

It does! Thank you very much!

To show $x_n$ is monotonically decreasing, it suffices to show $x_{n+1} -x_{n} < 0 $ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. First, we have $x_{n+1} -x_{n} =  \frac{2}{x_n} - \frac{x_n}{2}$, which is less than $0$ if $x_n > 2$ for all $n$. For the later claim, we can show it by induction: we know $x_1>2$. Suppose $x_n>2$, we need to show $x_{n+1}>2$, which is not too hard by realizing that the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x + 2/x)$ is increasing in $x$ for $x>2$ and $f(2)>2$.

Thank you but I don't want to use functions.
